# How to run proteowizzard on linux using wine?

Tags: mass-spectrometry

I am trying to run proteowizzard using wine to be able to convert raw mass spectrometry files to myML format. Following, [these instructions](http://tools.proteomecenter.org/wiki/index.php?title=Msconvert_Wine)` which seem terribly outdated. I am getting many issues. I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

We want to convert output from a ThermoFisher instrument to mzML or mzXML format.

```
> ~/software/proteowizzard>wine msconvert.exe 
> fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
> fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
> fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000380, 00000000):
> partial stub. err:module:import_dll Library VCOMP110.DLL (which is
> needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\baf2sql_c.dll") not
> found err:module:import_dll Library baf2sql_c.dll (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msconvert.exe") not
> found err:module:import_dll Library MSVCP140.dll (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msconvert.exe") not
> found err:module:import_dll Library VCRUNTIME140.dll (which is needed
> by L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msconvert.exe") not
> found err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
> (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msconvert.exe") not
> found err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
> (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msconvert.exe") not
> found err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
> (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msconvert.exe") not
> found err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
> (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msconvert.exe") not
> found err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
> (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msconvert.exe") not
> found err:module:import_dll Library
> api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msconvert.exe") not
> found err:module:import_dll Library
> api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msconvert.exe") not
> found err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
> (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msconvert.exe") not
> found err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
> (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msconvert.exe") not
> found err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
> (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msconvert.exe") not
> found err:module:import_dll Library MSVCP140.dll (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msparser.dll") not found
> err:module:import_dll Library VCRUNTIME140.dll (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msparser.dll") not found
> err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll (which
> is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msparser.dll") not found
> err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll (which
> is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msparser.dll") not found
> err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll (which
> is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msparser.dll") not found
> err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
> (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msparser.dll") not found
> err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll (which is
> needed by L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msparser.dll")
> not found err:module:import_dll Library
> api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msparser.dll") not found
> err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
> (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msparser.dll") not found
> err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll (which
> is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msparser.dll") not found
> err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll (which is
> needed by L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msparser.dll")
> not found err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
> (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msparser.dll") not found
> err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll (which
> is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msparser.dll") not found
> err:module:import_dll Library msparser.dll (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msconvert.exe") not
> found err:module:import_dll Library api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
> (which is needed by
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msconvert.exe") not
> found err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for
> L"Z:\\home\\swacker\\software\\proteowizzard\\msconvert.exe" failed,
> status c0000135
```

Comment: Which issues did you find? You mention wine, so I assume you are using a linux computer to run a program for windows. Could you add more information about the requirements of this program?

Comment: It might be better to ask this on [ubuntu.se], but either way please [edit] and show us _exactly_ what commands you ran and the _specific_ errors you are getting. We can't help you if you don't tell us what the symptoms are.

Comment: I am wondering whether there is anyone here who runs proteowizzard on linux, who knows how to set it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Docker [container](https://hub.docker.com/r/chambm/pwiz-skyline-i-agree-to-the-vendor-licenses).

All the vendor formats work except T2D, YEP, and FID.

Answer (score 1):

I sympathize ...
If it is a Mac just run 'PlayonMac' its a brilliant frontend for Wine without all the bugs and hassles it causes. Its free and available [here](https://www.playonmac.com/en/)